# Index printing issue

Tags: errors, compiling, indexing

I am writing an article with an index, and I'm using the makeidx package to do so.  I have made sure to include the `\makeindex` command in my preamble, and I have included a `\printindex` command near the end of my document.

On my desktop, where I am running TexMaker + TexLive, compilation of pdf-Latex results in no index being generated in the output PDF.

On my laptop, where I am running WinEdt + MikTex, everything seems to run fine.  In particular, the index is generated in the appropriate location.

I'm at a loss as to how to troubleshoot this inconsistency.  I've tried deleting all auxiliary files besides the source and recompiling on my desktop, but no dice.

Is there something simple I could be missing here?

Comment: You have to run `makeindex`. Look for it on some menu. So do `pdflatex+makeindex+pdflatex+pdflatex`.

Comment: @Sigur Ah!  I see, WinEdt was doing that automatically.  Thank you so much!  You should post that as an answer.

Comment: You are better off with `imakeidx` which runs `makeindex` automatically. Syntax is same. Just change `makeidx` to `imakeidx`.

Comment: @HarishKumar Interesting that is handy. As an aside, `imakeidx` seems to alter the formatting of the index.  In particular, right now I only have a single column of index entries because there is a small number, and it seems to want to change it to two columns.  Is there some way to override this?

Comment: Just do: `\makeindex[columns=1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run the external program `makeindex`. Use the Tools menu or press F12.

[image]

Or choose it near the blue arrow and press the arrow.

[image]

Or you can use the Options menu and configure the Quick Build (F1) to run that sequence of commands.